# What is Web Farm and Web garden in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-farm, web-garden

Could any one explain me the difference between the Web Farm and Web Garden with some real time scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Web farm and Web Garden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541860/what-is-the-difference-between-web-farm-and-web-garden)

Answer (score 4):

Web garden is when you have set many worker asp.net on the same machine (for the same web pages), Web farm is when you have many worker asp.net on the same web pages on different machines.

When you use web garder, you need to take care synchronization's on your program especial if you manipulate database.

When you use web farm you need to take care synchronization's of your database and take care about the view state to be the same on all machines.

Comment: do they have anything related to scaling up or scaling out?

Comment: @afr0 To scalling up or out is depends from your program design and not by the server, except in the case that you only have simple pages and not a big complicate database program.

Comment: a bit off topic though what do scaling up and out mean? i think i'm totally lost.

Comment: @afr0 To add more computers and more process to help with the web pages requests